# SQL Server - COALESCE WHEN NOTHING RETURNS , GET DEFAULT VALUE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to use Coalesce function in SQL Server to concatente multiple names. But when the conditon in the query returns no rows or nothing, I need to return a default value. I tried some condition using case statement but I can't figure it out what I missed.

```
declare @Names varchar(max) = '',
        @Key varchar(max) = 'ABC' 

select @Names = COALESCE(@Names, '') + isnull(T0.A, @Key) + ', ' 
from TData P
left join TNames T0 on T0.C + '\' + T0.D = P.@Key
where OBID=581464 
and ID < 1432081

select @Names
```

Comment: Do you know what is an [XYPropblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) ? Please edit your question to include sample data (DDL+DML please) and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with 2 minor changes to your current code, but I suspect this is an [XYProblem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and you might benefit more from editing your question to include sample data and desired results (so perhaps we can suggest a better solution).

Anyway, what I had in mind is this:

```sql
declare @Names varchar(max), -- remove the = '', so that @Names starts as null
        @Key varchar(max) = 'ABC' 

select @Names = COALESCE(@Names, '') + isnull(T0.A, @Key) + ', ' 
from TData P
left join TNames T0 on T0.C + '\' + T0.D = P.@Key -- ' (This is just to fix the coding colors)
where OBID=581464 
and ID < 1432081

select COALESCE(@Names, 'default value') -- since @Names started as null, and the query did not return any results, it's still null...
```

Comment: thank you for your post and your help.. i have figured it out what was the problem.. My Sql query is working as expected. the problem was the filter id, I had it wrong, and because of that he never find rows.. lol :)